# How to specify href="'.get_permalink().'" to allow certain links and deny others?

Tags: php, wordpress

The code below works for linking *all* thumbnails of a custom post type to their particular posts. What I need to do is allow some to link and others not. How can I set an argument to prevent some of these from linking?

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'casestudies', 'posts_per_page' => 18 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

echo '<div class="casestudy"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="anchor-hover">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '180,180' ).'</a></div>';

endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What is the condition where the image shouldn't be linked to?

Comment: some would link to an extended post, others would not.

Comment: What is an extended post? We can't read minds. Is there any meta information/indication what an extended post is? Based on what you asked in your question above the code that Vidhi gave you will work.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear. In Wordpress, custom post types have their own 'posts', each with its own url even if there's nothing more to that post than an image. If there's additional text, I want to link the thumbnail to that full post. If there's no additional info than I want this page to display the thumbnail with no link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'casestudies', 'posts_per_page' => 18 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
if($shouldlink) // your condition to check it should link or not
    echo '<div class="casestudy"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="anchor-hover">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '180,180' ).'</a></div>';
else
    echo '<div class="casestudy">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '180,180' ).'</div>';

endwhile; 
?>
```

Comment: thanks, how do I specify the if($shouldlink) for a particular post?

Comment: by that I mean, for a specific url?

Comment: If you want to check for specific post id, then replace `if($shouldlink)` with `if(get_the_ID() == 5)` where 5 is just for example and it will be replaced by your post id for which it should link. If there are multiple post for which you want to link, make array of that post and after that check using in_array

Comment: I also ready your above comment that you want to link only if additional text is present. If your additional text is saved in description / post content, check using `get_the_content` function. If you are not saving as post content, kindly specify how do you save it

Comment: Yes, `if(get_the_ID() == 5)` works for that post, and `if(get_the_content)` works for all posts with post content. I very much appreciate your help!